# In matlab, how to discontinue a ifelse condition in between and start from top again?

Tags: matlab

For example, I have

```
some calculations from some formulae
calculate r

if r<1
something
(the point where I want to discontinue and start the above calculations again)

else if r>tau
something

else if r==0
something

else
something

some calculations again after this
```

How can I discontinue the if/else and start all the calculation all over again from the top if my first condition is met (r<1) ...??

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this sung a loop around:

```
finished=false;
while ~finished
    %default case, finish if case is done
    finished=true;
    if r<1
        something
        %start from begin in this case:
        finished=false;
    elseif r>tau
        something
    elseif r==0
        something
    else
        something
    end

end
```

Comment: hi is it possible to contact you somehow, I need some more help on matlab?

Comment: Ask your questions here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If your calculations are being done withing a while or for-loop, use the CONTINUE or BREAK commands.

Comment: umm I have if and else if loop, and matlab does not allow continue or break in if/else?? what can I do?